# Pythonic way to calculate Covariance matrix with Diagonal and off Diagonal values having different rolling windows. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, covariance

I have a pandas dataframe of daily factor returns. My desired end result is to obtain the VcV matrix with the variance diagonal calculated with a rolling 1.5 year (358 days) and the off diagonal covariance values calculated off a rolling 3 year (756 day) window. for simplicity i am equally weighting the observations at this time.

my current function creates two multi index dataframe of covariance matrices I then use a for loop to substitute one diagonal for the other diagonal. This works;however, Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than calculating two multi-index dataframes?

```
def blendCovarianceMatrix(daily_returns, var_window = 358, cov_window = 756 ):
    varianceMatrix = daily_returns.rolling(int(var_window)).cov()
    covarianceMatrix = daily_returns.rolling(int(cov_window)).cov()
    datelist = covarianceMatrix.dropna().index.get_level_values("DataDate").unique()
    for dates in datelist:
        np.fill_diagonal(covarianceMatrix.loc[dates].values,np.diag(varianceMatrix.loc[dates]))
    return covarianceMatrix, datelist
```